# QT: Set FPS for an Application

Tags: c++, qt, webview

I am new in QT. I want to create an application, In which i can set the FPS on basis of user input.
Is there any way to achieve this.
Currently i am loading my URL using QWebView. current FPS is constant and i cant change it. So is there any way in QT to change the FPS on QWebView or in other classes.

Comment: What is FPS? Frames per second? That does not make much sense on a webview...

Comment: Yes FPS( Frames per second), is there any other class or methods using which i can set FPS  in QT. like Qwebengine or any other. if possible please provide an example.

Comment: It's not possible. A `QWebView` will update the output widget as fast as possible, barring any internal limits imposed by webkit.

Comment: thnx, Is it possible to create a browser in which we can set FPS. Sorry but i could not able to find such example(to set FPS for URL) in QT.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Sometimes, when you want functionality that no one else has needed so far - and really lots of people use browsers! - your design might be somehow broken.

Comment: Actually, I have an URL. which contain flash content. so i want to create application where user can set FPS for flash content.

Comment: one more question: can we set FPS using  QWebEngineView

Comment: Is the Flash content a movie or an animation? For movies, FPS are dictated by the movie and you can't change that. For animation... I suppose it depends on the computer's speed. Again, the whole notion of setting the FPS does not make much sense in this context.

Comment: Flash content is an animation. i am getting it from a URL on my application. But is it possible to set the frame rate on application side without make changes on server side?.